# SQLite reference warning processor mismatch

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I just changed from SQL server to SQLite, everything went perfectly fine, everything is working fine, the only thing that bothers me is that I get a warning about a mismatch with the SQLite reference, below the warning message:

> Warning  1   There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of
>   the 
>       project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference 
>       "System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.84.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139, 
>       processorArchitecture=x86", "x86". This mismatch may cause
>        runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your
>        project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures 
>       between your project and references, or take a 
>       dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.
>         LivePigeonClient

Did I install the wrong reference? Or do I really need to set the target of my application to x86? Because that is not what I want, does anybody have some suggestions about what to do, to get rid of this warning?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish to use this ADO.NET connector, you will have to specify the architecture for your program. This is because this assembly is a mixed mode assembly - it contains native code - and thus it cannot run under other architectures. If you do not specify an architecture for your executable, the runtime will use a 64-bit instance on 64-bit machines and the referenced assembly will not be loadable.

Comment: One solution is to set your project to x86. This will correct the warning, but your project will always run as a 32-bit process, even on 64-bit machines. Another option is to make two releases, one for each architecture, and reference the proper assembly.

Comment: Just read this form, they say it isn't solved yet: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/303.aspx     But if I change my project solution to x86 it will still work on x64 machines?

Comment: Yes, of course it will. It will run under the 32-bit WoW compatibility layer included in 64-bit versions of Windows. For further reference, see this FAQ entry: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q12

Answer (score 6):

Install the Nuget package "System.Data.SQLite (x86/x64)" to eliminate this warning.

Answer (score 0):

Problem which I solved on 2020 ( Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019)
follow bellow step

Build -> configuration manager -> Active solution platform -> select x86