# System.Data.SQLite 1.0.108 gives "There was a mismatch between the processor architecture" warning

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, system.data.sqlite, configurationmanager, cpu-architecture

I had a Visual Studio solution that was using System.Data.SQLite version 1.0.97. When I used NuGet to update to the latest version (1.0.108), I started getting this warning:

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project
>   being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference
>   "System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.108.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139, processorArchitecture=x86", "x86".
>   This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the
>   targeted processor architecture of your project through the
>   Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures
>   between your project and references, or take a dependency on
>   references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted
>   processor architecture of your project.

My solution uses "Any CPU" and I don't want to change it to "x86" just to fix this one problem. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My solution uses "Any CPU" and I don't want to change it to "x86" just to fix this one problem. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

As Anton in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite) said, `System.Data.SQLite` has a dependency on `System.Data.SQLite.Core`, which is a is a mixed assembly, i.e. it contains both managed code and native code. Therefore a particular `System.Data.SQLite.dll` is either `x86` or `x64`, but never both architectures.

> So Microsoft is just trying to warn you when you state that your
>   project is compatible with "Any CPU" but you have a dependency on a
>   project or .dll assembly that is either x86 or x64. Because you have
>   an x86 dependency, technically your project is therefore not "Any CPU"
>   compatible.

You can edit your project file and add this property group and setting to supresse the warning:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>None</ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And if you are very aware of your solution architecture and you do not need the assembly `SQLite.Interop.dll`, you can use "System.Data.SQLite (x86/x64)" to eliminate this warning.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163354/sqlite-dll-for-x86-x64-architectures) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113532/how-do-i-fix-the-visual-studio-compile-error-mismatch-between-processor-archit?rq=1) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Adding nuget package seems to solve the problem. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983165/sqlite-reference-warning-processor-mismatch